# How to make print use desktop media queries?

Tags: css, printing

I am attempting to add some print functionality to my page, but I am having an issue where when I print, it is printing as if it is mobile. How can I make it so that when someone hits print it prints the desktop version?

```js
$('.print-btn').click(function(e) {
  window.print();
});
```

```css
.visible-desktop {
  display:none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .visible-desktop {
    display:block;
  }
  
  .visible-mobile {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="visible-desktop">Viewing from desktop</div>
  <div class="visible-mobile">Viewing from mobile</div>
</div>

<a class="print-btn" href="#">Pring</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `@media print` rule at the bottom of your stylesheet:

```
@media print {
  .visible-desktop {
    display:block;
  }
  .visible-mobile {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would rather not take this approach as my actual implementation includes a lot more content than the sample.

Comment: Well,, then try to use `@media screen and (min-width:768px) {..` (without `screen`) to avoid the limitation of that rule to screens.

Comment: I tried that per @SLaks suggestion, but the browser continues to print the mobile version, even without `screen`.

Comment: Yeah, just not going to work for me. Some elements are table cells, other elements are block and others are inline-block, so I can't just do a `display:block;` on hidden mobile elements and call it a day. There's gotta be some way to force the print functionality to use a specific, non-print, media query.

Comment: couldn't you simply copy everything that's in the media query into an `@media print` query?

Answer (score 0):

```
only screen
```

This excludes print.  If you want to include print, don't write that.

Comment: I tried removing the `only screen and` part, but it's still displaying the mobile version when I print.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick one state (probably desktop) and make it the "default", by moving that state outside media queries.

The other states should override the default state's properties in media queries.