# Increase page title font size in web page print mode

Tags: html

I have a html page contains a table and I want to increase the font size of **page title generated** when printing the page from the browser directly by clicking 
**ctrl + P**

[image]

I do a lot of search about this requirement but i didn't find any solution.

The idea that we cannot style the text inside the  tag, can anyone suggest a hack or alternative solution ?

**Note that I need this way to show the title, I don't want to create a tag and styling it then showing it in all pages.**

```html
<head>
    <title> When print the page, the generated title taken from this tag but we cannot styling this text!! </title>
</head>
```

---

Update:
my question is not duplicated as the community member understand, he said that my question duplicate with this :

[How to make print use desktop media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472259/how-to-make-print-use-desktop-media-queries)

[How can I have different CSS when I print or print preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564259/how-can-i-have-different-css-when-i-print-or-print-preview)

[show div only when printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973912/show-div-only-when-printing)

Again this is not what I'm looking for please read my question carefully. I want to style the generated title in print mode.

Comment: Read this article and adapt to your needs. That's exactly what you want.
https://flaviocopes.com/css-printing/

Comment: @IuraVarzari Thank you for the article but I cannot find anything to do my requirement,I know how to give scenically css for print mode but I need to access the page title its not accessible from css because its generated when click ctrl + p or choose print page not added by me  :(  thank you again.